# Change format of csv file

Tags: excel, csv, excel-formula

I have a csv file that is in the following format:

```
name1
Date,Type
11/06/2015 18:13:42,Red
name2
Date,Type
08/06/2015 18:53:38,Blue
name3
Date,Type
10/06/2015 17:13:33,Yellow
10/06/2015 17:55:11,Green
name4
Date,Type
15/06/2015 11:19:01,Blue
10/06/2015 13:45:05,Orange
name5
Date,Type
10/06/2015 15:05:14,Purple
```

---

I need to change the format to the below? Can someone recommend a way 
to do it?:

```
name1,11/06/2015 18:13:42,Red
name2,08/06/2015 18:53:38,Blue
name3,10/06/2015 17:13:33,Yellow
name3,10/06/2015 17:55:11,Green
name4,15/06/2015 11:19:01,Blue
name4,10/06/2015 13:45:05,Orange
name5,10/06/2015 15:05:14,Purple
```

Note some names have more than 1 entry.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

> This routine uses a **Scripting.Dictionary**. You will need to go into the VBE's Tools ► References and add the **Microsoft Scripting Runtime** to your project before you can use it.

If you can open the CSV as the active workbook then this short routine should reorganize your data.

```
Sub collate_CSV()
    Dim rw As Long, lr As Long, v As Long
    Dim dRECs As New Scripting.Dictionary
    Dim vKEY As Variant, vITM As Variant, vVALs As Variant
    
    dRECs.CompareMode = TextCompare
    ReDim vVALs(1 To 1)
    
    With Sheet1   '<-CSVs almost always have their single worksheet codename as Sheet1
        lr = .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        For rw = lr To 2 Step -1
            Select Case LCase(.Cells(rw, 1).Value2)
                Case vbNullString
                    'do nothing
                Case "date,type"
                    ReDim Preserve vVALs(1 To UBound(vVALs) - 1)
                    dRECs.Add Key:=.Cells(rw - 1, 1).Value2, Item:=Join(vVALs, ChrW(8203))
                    ReDim vVALs(1 To 1)
                    .Cells(rw - 1, 1).Resize(Rows.Count - rw + 1, 1).EntireRow.Delete
                Case Else
                    vVALs(UBound(vVALs)) = .Cells(rw, 1).Value2
                    ReDim Preserve vVALs(1 To UBound(vVALs) + 1)
            End Select
            
        Next rw
        
        For Each vKEY In dRECs
            vITM = Split(dRECs.Item(vKEY), ChrW(8203))
            For v = LBound(vITM) To UBound(vITM)
                .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0) = _
                  vKEY & Chr(44) & vITM(v)
            Next v
        Next vKEY
        
        .Rows(1).EntireRow.Delete
        
    End With
    
End Sub
```

Your results should be similar to the following:

[image: Collate CSV with Scripting Dictionary]

The results are reversed from the original. That is a factor of progressing from the bottom of the data to the top, deleting spent records as the work advances.

Comment: Hi thanks for the comment, it appears this doesn't work but it also doesn't throw an error. I made sure the tab is Sheet1

Comment: @SB77 - Unfortunately it works for me on the supplied sample data. I'm unclear on how to proceed without seeing a more complete data set.

Comment: @SB77 - I suspect that you are opening the .CSV with a double-click and that the data is coming into a new worksheet split by commas into columns A and B. That does not represent the data that you showed as a sample but it is a logical guess as to the problem.